# how to clear console with Kotlin

Tags: android, windows, kotlin

I'm creating a program that runs in console in Kotlin (android stodio)
some times I need to clear console to show other things or update informations

how should I do that

(I'm using windows)
for example how can I call "cls"
cant find any way to solve it

Answer (score 1):

You may use this process.
**Using ANSI escape sequences:**

You can print specific ANSI escape sequences to manipulate the console display. For clearing the screen, you can use the following:

```
print("\u001b[2J") // Clear the entire screen
print("\u001b[0;0H") // Move the cursor to the top left corner
```